VS Code просто выводит слово Python в output и терминал
перезагрузка не помогла, переустановка vscode не помогла, интерпретатор стоит последней 12й версии. уже переместил папку с ним просто на сам диск, написал в настройках vscode новый путь к интепретатору без кириллицы и всё без толку. интерпретатор пробовал и из windows store и с официального сайта но итог один. он просто выводит одно единственное слово Python. расширения тоже обновлял. к слову винда 11. на 10 работало норм. не знаю что делать подскажите!!((

Ну это питон из windows store так отзывается. А из командной строки нормально python вызывается?

из командной также отзывается

Гляньте на всякий случай сюда

спасибо огромное! всё работает
